# Why won't my enabled systemd service start on boot?

Tags: systemd

I have the following systemd unit file in `/etc/systemd/system/emacs.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor
Documentatin=man:emacs(1) info:Emacs


[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(progn (setq kill-emacs-hook nil) (kill-emacs))"
Restart=always
Environment=DISPLAY=:%i
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I want this to start on boot, so I have entered `systemctl enable emacs`

However, each time my service reboots, `systemctl status emacs` shows:

```
● emacs.service - Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/emacs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

But then entering `systemctl start emacs` and checking the status returns:

```
● emacs.service - Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/emacs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-11-11 23:03:59 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 3151 ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3154 (emacs)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 7.6M
      CPU: 53ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/emacs.service
           └─3154 /usr/bin/emacs --daemon
```

How can I get this process to successfully start on boot?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have no idea why but to get this to work I:

deleted `Environment=DISPLAY=:%i`

added a `User=` variable

Made sure the correct file was in `/etc/systemd/system/emacs.service` (earlier it had been a hard link)

and re-ran `systemctl enable emacs`

This made it work.

**EDIT**
The real problem here is that I had a typo at line 3:
`Documentatin`

I found this by checking `journalctl`.  I suggest anyone who has issues with a systemd script do the same as there was no error sent to stderr.

Comment: Does that also work on a reboot? I guess if the daemon mode does not require an X11 connection, then there is no need for the `After=...` I mentioned.

Comment: Yes it works after reboot.  This is not a graphical Emacs so no X11 is needed.  That was just a line I copied from an example and didn't pay attention.

Comment: +1 for the real problem being a typo. My `WantedBy` was wrong (`mult-user` != `multi-user`)

Comment: +1 on the `journalctl` comment. This is going to be your most powerful debugging tool moving forward. Helped me find the issue with my system, which was totally different. Although, `journalctl` will give you a lot of log vomit, so pass the `-f` flag for `journalctl -f`

Comment: I found `systemctl list-dependencies` to also be useful for diagnosing "won't start at boot" issues.  The system I was working on wasn't actually starting `network.target`, so my script wasn't running because its "parent" wasn't part of the boot.

Answer (score 4):

You have a DISPLAY environment variable, that means you want X11 to be started. So you need to have a way to block your service until then.

This is done using [the `After=...` option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=).

I haven't done it myself, so I cannot say that it would work, but it is likely something to do with `graphical.target`.

```
[Unit]
After=graphical.target
```

Another possibility, if the X server does not start immediately (i.e. you have a login screen with lightdm or such), then you may have to use [`WantedBy=...`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#WantedBy=) instead:

```
[Unit]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

---

If you get tired of getting it to work with systemd, you may want to look into the usual way X-Windows managers make it work.

There is the `~/.xprofile` file, which works like the `~/.bashrc` file.

There is also the `~/.config/autostart/*.desktop` files. It will automatically start all the applications defined in there.

These solutions are not system wide, though, in case you have multiple users, each one would have to have their own entry. Also, it does not start the application as root, but you, instead.

---

As a side note, the "loaded + inactive (dead)" message means that systemd had a hard time to start the process and as a result decided to *abandon* it. You can manually test that the `name.service` works once you rebooted using:

```
systemctl stop <service-name>
systemctl start <service-name>
```

This will *refresh* the status and start the service properly, assuming the info is correct. You can then check the status again to see additional details:

```
systemctl status <service-name>
```

Comment: Hm, I deleted that entire line and nothing changed.  Also, (as I said in my question) it starts fine by running systemctl start emacs).

Comment: see my updated question. I had a typo in `Documentatin` .  Your hint about `journalctl` helped me here.

Answer (score 3):

Check where is your link after you enabled the service. Just to add what I had with this. When I execuded `sudo systemctl enable myserevice.service` it created the link in the folder `multi-user.target.wants` but not in the real `multi-user.target.wants`. It created in some new folder with the same name. I have had some extra character in line `WantedBy=multi-user.target` that my text editor didn't show. So, I don't know what it was. I just c/p from another .service file and after that I enabled again and now the link is in the correct folder

Answer (score 2):

ooh this is interesting.

Picking a random service unit and staring at it, it depends on a specific target instead of `default.target`.  The latter is symbolic... a configured link to a specific target, semantically it doesn't make sense.  (See `systemctl set-default`)

That might explain why your service shows as `disabled` after you enable it.  Try replacing `default.target` in your service file with `multi-user.target`, for example.

(Not reporting an error when failing to enable seems like a defect in systemd.  I almost wonder if you now have a directory `/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants`).

Comment: The journalctl command tells you what broke (why the enable failed, for example.) As for the link, it is not required if you create your own personal service. It does matter if you create a package that you want others to install/remove, etc.

Comment: @AlexisWilke That would be even worse!  Why would it be written to report some errors to stderr and others to the journal?

Comment: It writes everything to the journal. From what I've seen, you only see a very basic, systemd specific, error if it could not start the daemon.

Comment: user did not report even a basic error, they believed the operation had succeeded and therefore proceeded to reboot. at face value, there is a defect in systemd. Users also have failure modes, but it didn't sound to me like overlooking an error message completely was a very likely one in this question.

Comment: @sourcejedi I have no idea how you knew this but yes, I now have a listing at `/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants`  Inside that is my service files.  And yes, I had no idea there was any error.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in several service files of Debian:

```
# systemctl enable watchdog
Synchronizing state of watchdog.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable watchdog
# find /etc/systemd/ | grep watch
# tail -n2 /lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service

[Install]
```

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=82&t=218609&p=1406567#p1406567
https://forum.armbian.com/topic/9115-still-dont-know-where-to-report-bugs-watchdogservice-refuses-to-start-due-to-broken-service-file/

The distribution level fix is to

```
echo "WantedBy=default.target" >> /lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service
systemctl daemon-reexec
systemctl enable watchdog
systemctl stop watchdog.service
systemctl start watchdog.service
```

There are many manual alternatives to this.